# Do I need to enable a Google Map API key and how to embed it in 2017?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm buildingh someones website and I want to include a Google Map. I have asked  him to create an API key.

I tried to include it like this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_KEYq=Shop+Name,City+Name" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```

1. Is this the right way how to include it? I read the Google docs and I think this should work.
2. However, it tells me "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API."
   Does he need to enable the key for the domain in the Google Backend first or did I include it the wrong way?

Comment: First check if Google Maps Embed API is enabled in the project: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key#detailed-guide

Comment: I did check that. It's restricted for the URL, but still doesn't work :/

Comment: Did you check that Embed API presents in the list of enabled APIs? API key restriction is another question. The error message says that Embed API is not authorized to be used with the project where you generated an API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `&` between your url parameters.  Change:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_KEYq=Shop+Name,City+Name
```

To:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_KEY&q=Shop+Name,City+Name
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow. Is it still neccessary to somehow activate the API key for a domain in the Google backend?